# (Spivak - chap 7 - problem 6) my solution is wrong? I’m doubt about

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I'm in doubt about my arguments for this problem, in addition to having thought of an alternative argument after writing the solution. Please give me feedback on them, constructive criticism, and of course if they are valid.

Best regards.

**Suppose that f is a continuous function on [-1,1] such that $x^2+(f(x))^2=1$ for all $x$. Show that either $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for all $x$ or else $f(x)=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for all $x$.**

*(extra): $f(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{1-x^2}, & \mbox{if } x \in [-1,1) \\-\sqrt{1-x^2}, & \mbox{if } x = 1 \end{cases}$, is continuous(right?), so we have more than 2 options for f, contradicting the problem? or we consider that equivalent to $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}?$*

## remarks:

1. Since $x^2+(f(x))^2=1$, we have $f(x)=0$ iff $x=1$ or $x=-1$.
2. Since $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$, WLOG if $f(a)=\sqrt{1-a^2}$ for $-1<a<1$, we have $f(a)>0$, so exist $\delta > 0$, such that $0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ with $\epsilon < |f(a)|$, then $f(x) > f(a)-\epsilon > 0$ for $x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$. Therefore $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$.
3. As a result of (2), we have that $f(a+\delta)=\sqrt{1-(a+\delta)^2}$. Because suppose $f(a’)=-\sqrt{1-(a’)^2}$ for $a’=a+\delta$, follow that $f(a’)<0$, where exists $\delta’>0$, which $0<|x-a’|<\delta’ \implies |f(x)-f(a’)|<\epsilon$ with $\epsilon<|f(a’)|$ so $f(x) <f(a’)+\epsilon < 0$ for $x \in (a’-\delta’,a’+\delta’)$, then $f(x)=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $x \in (a’-\delta’, a’+\delta’)$, this is a contradiction because $a’-\delta’ < a’$ so exist $x$ that satisfy both $a<x<a+\delta$ in (item 2) and $a’-\delta’<x<a’$. Hence $f(a’)=\sqrt{1-(a’)^2}$

## Solution:

Suppose that $f(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{1-x^2}, & \mbox{if } x \in S_{1}\\ -\sqrt{1-x^2}, & \mbox{if } x \in S_{2}\end{cases}$, where $S_{1} ≠ \emptyset$ and $S_{2} ≠ \emptyset$.

WLOG Assume that, $f(a)=\sqrt{1-a^2}$ for $-1<a<1$. Consider the set $A=\{y: a\leq y \leq 1 \mbox{ and } f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2} \mbox{ for } x\in [a, y]\}$, we know that $a \in A$, and for all $y \in A$ we have $y \leq 1$, then A have least upper bound, denote $k=\sup{A} \leq 1$.

We will prove that $k \in A$. First:

- if $k = 1$, then $f(k)=0=\sqrt{1-k^2}=-\sqrt{1-k^2}$, following $f(k)=\sqrt{1-k^2}$
- if $k<1$, suppose that $f(k)=-\sqrt{1-k^2}$, where $f(k)<0$. Using remark (2), we have exist $\delta > 0$ such that $x \in (k-\delta, k+\delta)$ then $f(x)=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Being $y\leq k$ for $y \in A$, we have $y\leq(k-\delta)$ for all $y$ in A, which is a contradiction, by $k-\delta<k$. Therefore $f(k)=\sqrt{1-k^2}$.

Second: Suppose that $k \notin A$, so exist $y_{1},y_{2} \in A$ where for $x \in [y1,y2]$ or $x \in (y1,y2)$ we have $f(x)=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Using remark (2) and (3), we show this is impossible.

Hence $k \in A$. Suppose that $k<1$, we have by remark (2), that exists $\delta > 0$, where $k+\delta \in A$, being $k=\sup{A}<k+\delta$ leads us to a contradiction. Hence $k=1$, so for all $x \in [a,1]$; $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Similar to prove for $x \in [-1,a]$.

Hence $S_{1} = \emptyset$ or $S_{2} = \emptyset$

$\blacksquare$

## Alternative:

After write the solution, i see that:

Suppose that $S_{1} \neq \emptyset$ and $S_{2} \neq \emptyset$, follow that exists $y1, y2 \in [-1,1]$, which for all $x$ in $[y_{1},y_{2}]$ or in $(y_{1}, y_{2})$ we have (WLOG) $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Observe that, (WLOG) for $[y_{1}, y_{2}$, we must have $w_{1}, w_{2} \in [-1,1]$ such that for $x \in (w_{1},y_{1}) \or (y_{2}, w_{2})$; $f(x)=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Because, if does not exists $w_{1},w_{2}$, we have $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$

Now, we can use the remarks (2), (3), to show this is impossible, following that not exists $y_{1}, y_{2}$.

Comment: Just addressing the part right after the question statement that you labeled "extra": note that that's literally the same function (it takes on all the same values between $-1$ and $1$, including the endpoints) -- remember that the function is not the same as the formula defining the function.

Comment: Regarding your (extra) statement, a function is defined by how it maps inputs to outputs. It doesn't matter what formulas we use to describe that map, and as you can readily see, at $x = 1$, 
$$
- \sqrt{1 - x^2} = 0 = \sqrt{1 - x^2}.
$$

Comment: Well, @hunter, it seems we came here to leave effectively the same comment. *Cheers!*

Comment: Thank you very much @hunter. I was thinking about it. But I had my doubts.

Comment: You too @SammyBlack